# SQL Error Turkish_CI_AS and SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have query in SQL SERVER 2008 like this. And this is working.

```
SELECT C.HESAP_NO, B.TEKLIF_NO1 + '/' + B.TEKLIF_NO2 AS 'TEKLIF',
    C.MUS_K_ISIM,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),B.ISL_TAR,103) AS 'TARIH', SUM(
    ISNULL(CAST(B.ODENEN_ANAPARA AS FLOAT),0)+ISNULL(CAST(B.FAIZ AS FLOAT),0)+
    ISNULL(CAST(B.BSMV AS FLOAT),0)+ISNULL(CAST(B.GECIKME_FAIZ AS FLOAT),0)+
    ISNULL(CAST(B.GECIKME_BSMV AS FLOAT),0)) AS 'YATAN', 
    (CASE WHEN C.DOVIZ_KOD = 21 THEN 'EUR' WHEN C.DOVIZ_KOD = 2 THEN 'USD' WHEN C.DOVIZ_KOD = 1 THEN 'TL' END) AS 'KUR', D.T_SR_ACK

    FROM TAKIP A, YAZ..MARDATA.BIR_TAHSIL B, 
    YAZ..MARDATA.S_TEKLIF C,P_TAKIP_SR D

    WHERE B.TEKLIF_NO1 = C.TEKLIF_NO1
    AND B.TEKLIF_NO2 = C.TEKLIF_NO2
    AND A.T_HESAP_NO = C.HESAP_NO
    AND A.T_SRM = D.T_SR_ID
    AND A.T_STATU = 2
    AND A.T_SRM <> 6
        GROUP BY C.HESAP_NO, B.TEKLIF_NO1 + '/' + B.TEKLIF_NO2, C.MUS_K_ISIM,B.ISL_TAR,C.DOVIZ_KOD, D.T_SR_ACK
```

BUT, when i made little changing on this query like this;

```
SELECT E.HESAP, B.TEKLIF_NO1 + '/' COLLATE Turkish_CI_AS + B.TEKLIF_NO2 AS 'TEKLIF',
    E.MUSTERI,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),B.ISL_TAR,103) AS 'TARIH', SUM(
    ISNULL(CAST(B.ODENEN_ANAPARA AS FLOAT),0)+ISNULL(CAST(B.FAIZ AS FLOAT),0)+
    ISNULL(CAST(B.BSMV AS FLOAT),0)+ISNULL(CAST(B.GECIKME_FAIZ AS FLOAT),0)+
    ISNULL(CAST(B.GECIKME_BSMV AS FLOAT),0)) AS 'YATAN', 
    (CASE WHEN C.DOVIZ_KOD = 21 THEN 'EUR' WHEN C.DOVIZ_KOD = 2 THEN 'USD' WHEN C.DOVIZ_KOD = 1 THEN 'TL' END) AS 'KUR',
    E.AVUKAT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),A.ICRA_TAR,103) AS 'İCRA TARİHİ', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),A.HACIZ_TAR,103) AS 'HACİZ TARİHİ'
    FROM TAKIP A, YAZ..MARDATA.BIR_TAHSIL B, 
    YAZ..MARDATA.S_TEKLIF C,P_TAKIP_SR D, AVUKAT E
    WHERE B.TEKLIF_NO1 = C.TEKLIF_NO1
    AND B.TEKLIF_NO2 = C.TEKLIF_NO2
    AND A.T_HESAP_NO = C.HESAP_NO
    AND C.HESAP_NO = B.HESAP_NO
    AND B.HESAP_NO = E.HESAP
    AND A.T_SRM = D.T_SR_ID
    AND A.T_STATU = 2
    AND A.T_SRM <> 6
GROUP BY C.HESAP_NO, B.TEKLIF_NO1 + '/' + B.TEKLIF_NO2,B.ISL_TAR,C.DOVIZ_KOD, E.HESAP, E.MUSTERI, E.AVUKAT, A.ICRA_TAR, A.HACIZ_TAR
```

I getting an error like this

```
Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 16
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Turkish_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.
```

Anybody have an idea for this error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Error with "Turkish_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829538/sql-error-with-turkish-ci-as-and-sql-latin1-general-cp1-ci-as)

Comment: What is the collation and datatype of the `TEKLIF_NO1` column? Why have you added an explicit collation to the 2nd query if the first query is working?

Comment: @Linus - It looks like the OP has implemented the recommendation from that question and it has caused some other problem?

Comment: @Martin TEKLIF_NO1 is VARCHAR2(6 BYTE). Because i want to update some conditions first query. Second query is more different the first one.

Comment: If the first query works the problem is probably somewhere else actually. You'll need to comment out bits of the query until you find the bit with the problem then add an appropriate `collate` clause there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to replicate your collate clause in your group by expression also:

```
SELECT E.HESAP, B.TEKLIF_NO1 + '/' COLLATE Turkish_CI_AS + B.TEKLIF_NO2 AS 'TEKLIF',
    E.MUSTERI,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),B.ISL_TAR,103) AS 'TARIH', SUM(
    ISNULL(CAST(B.ODENEN_ANAPARA AS FLOAT),0)+ISNULL(CAST(B.FAIZ AS FLOAT),0)+
    ISNULL(CAST(B.BSMV AS FLOAT),0)+ISNULL(CAST(B.GECIKME_FAIZ AS FLOAT),0)+
    ISNULL(CAST(B.GECIKME_BSMV AS FLOAT),0)) AS 'YATAN', 
    (CASE WHEN C.DOVIZ_KOD = 21 THEN 'EUR' WHEN C.DOVIZ_KOD = 2 THEN 'USD' WHEN C.DOVIZ_KOD = 1 THEN 'TL' END) AS 'KUR',
    E.AVUKAT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),A.ICRA_TAR,103) AS 'İCRA TARİHİ', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),A.HACIZ_TAR,103) AS 'HACİZ TARİHİ'
    FROM TAKIP A, YAZ..MARDATA.BIR_TAHSIL B, 
    YAZ..MARDATA.S_TEKLIF C,P_TAKIP_SR D, AVUKAT E
    WHERE B.TEKLIF_NO1 = C.TEKLIF_NO1
    AND B.TEKLIF_NO2 = C.TEKLIF_NO2
    AND A.T_HESAP_NO = C.HESAP_NO
    AND C.HESAP_NO = B.HESAP_NO
    AND B.HESAP_NO = E.HESAP
    AND A.T_SRM = D.T_SR_ID
    AND A.T_STATU = 2
    AND A.T_SRM <> 6
GROUP BY C.HESAP_NO, B.TEKLIF_NO1 + '/' COLLATE Turkish_CI_AS + B.TEKLIF_NO2,B.ISL_TAR,C.DOVIZ_KOD, E.HESAP, E.MUSTERI, E.AVUKAT, A.ICRA_TAR, A.HACIZ_TAR
```